# Add input mask on Wordpress Login page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to add an input mask into the wp-login.php file so that the username can only be entered in the format of 1 lettter followed by 9 digits e.g. u828382901 and for an error to be received if the format was not followed.

I have attempted to use several plugins to modify the login page but it seems like I must enter the login file and edit the php directly.

My attempted php code is;

```
<?php
function myplugin_check_fields( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $username ) {

if ( ! preg_match('/u[0-9]{9}/', $_POST['username'] ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'username_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid user code.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
}

return $errors;
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_check_fields', 10, 3 );
?>
```

** I understand the php is probably a mess, its just my best attempt at writing in php

Thanks

Comment: `add_filter(` won't be fired. You also should use anchors, currently this allows more than 10 characters.

Comment: Sorry i was pretty certain the php isnt correct at all, just tried with all the knowledge I have

Comment: `if ( ! preg_match('/u[0-9]{9}/', $_POST['username'] ) ) {` is syntactically correct PHP, but the regex should probably be `/^u[0-9]{9}$/` so you only allow those 10 characters. The `add_filter` won't fire because you `return` before it, this exits your function. I don't know what you need to do with the WP though so perhaps this is all unneeded.

Comment: ah okay ill make sure to do some more research on it, thank you. My goal is to have the username textbox in the login/registration page of WP have an input mask